# LPR Printing InputSlot Issues

Tags: unix, printing, lpr

I am printing from a Unix system to a Xerox Phaser 4510 (altho I have also had issues printing to a Xerox WorkCentre 7765).

I am using LPR and trying to choose the InputSlot

The lpoptions show the following options:

```
InputSlot/Paper Tray: Tray1 *Tray2 Tray3 Tray4 ManualFeed Tray6
```

And here is a sample command that I am using:

```
lpr -P printer -o InputSlot=Tray1 test.pdf.ps
```

Here is the problem:

```
Tray1 = Gives me Tray2
Tray2 = Gives me Tray3
Tray3 = Gives me Tray4

Tray4, ManualFeed, Tray6 = Tray2 (the default tray)
```

If I change the default tray in either LPR, the printer settings, or both. LPR still sends tray2 as the default, where as printing from a windows machine or mac, would use the new default tray.

I have also tried Tray0, and several other things, but I have not found a way to get it to print on tray 1.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The wrong PPD was being used. Changed and is now working!